# Is the transpose of a matrix exponential with itself positive semi-definite under certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, matrix-exponential

Given is a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with linearly independent eigenvectors $\boldsymbol{u}_1,...,\boldsymbol{u}_n$ and corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. Additionally is given a $\delta\in\mathbb{R}_+$.

Assuming that the eigenvalues are real, then is it universally true that
$$(e^{\boldsymbol{A}\delta}-\boldsymbol{I})^T(e^{\boldsymbol{A}t}-\boldsymbol{I})$$ is positive semi-definite (PSD) for $t\in[0,\delta]$?

And if that is the case, then is it also true that
$$(e^{\boldsymbol{A}\delta}-\boldsymbol{I})^T(e^{\boldsymbol{A}\delta}-\boldsymbol{I}) - (e^{\boldsymbol{A}\delta}-\boldsymbol{I})^T(e^{\boldsymbol{A}t}-\boldsymbol{I})$$
is also PSD for the same interval?

Thanks!

Comment: Since it has a complete set of linearly independent eigenvectors, $A$ is diagonalizable: There is some $Q$ such that $A = Q^{-1}DQ$ where $D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ and therefore for any scalar $r, e^{rA} = Q^{-1}\text{diag}(e^{r\lambda_1},...,e^{r\lambda_n})Q$.

Comment: Hey, thanks but I am already aware of that. My question is different.